# how do I insert the response from requests results into the listbox on tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests

I have a problem with my code, how do I insert or enter the response from requests results into the listbox and can the results be put in the middle of the listbox, I'm new to using tkinter, this is the code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")
root.geometry('500x450')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Cek Url")

c1 = "#00ee00"
c2 = "#222222"
c3 = "#111111"

root.tk_setPalette(background=c2,foreground=c1,activeBackground=c3,activeForeground=c2,highlightColor=c1,highlightBackground=c1)

Label(root,text = 'CHECK URL',bg="black", fg ="cyan", font ='aerial 20 bold').place(x=180, y=35)
link = StringVar()
link_enter = Entry(root, width = 70,textvariable = link).place(x = 32, y = 100)

def ms():
    messagebox.showinfo("About","Simple URL Check")

def main():
    request = "https://unshorten.me/raw/" + link.get()
    response = requests.get(request).text
    print(response)

frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(width="370", height="215",x="60", y="133")
listbox = Listbox(frame, width="59",height="6")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

Button(root,text = 'Check Url', font = 'aerial 15 bold' ,bg = 'cyan', padx = 2, fg="black", command=main).place(x=203 ,y = 375)
Button(root,text = 'About', font = 'aerial 15 bold' ,bg = 'cyan', padx = 2, fg="black", command=ms).place(x=25 ,y = 375)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of `print` use the `insert` method that `Listbox`es have (for example in your case `listbox.insert('end', response)`) (also there is no middle for the listbox, are you sure you want to use `Listbox` at all? why don't you just `config`ure a `Label` or sth like that?)

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for the listbox? There are documented methods for inserting data into the listbox. It's not clear why you need our help here, since the answer can be found in the documentation.

Comment: ok, sorry i made a mistake, i didn't read the whole documentation, and now i'm starting to understand, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place the listbox into the frame.
The text will show up after you insert it then.

Then you can use the `listbox.insert('end', response)` as a commenter said.
You can also make the function delete the last response.

You can find a lot you would want to know about listbox [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm).

Up to you to figure out how you wish to format the text/output. :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")
root.geometry('500x450')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Cek Url")

c1 = "#00ee00"
c2 = "#222222"
c3 = "#111111"

root.tk_setPalette(background=c2,foreground=c1,activeBackground=c3,activeForeground=c2,highlightColor=c1,highlightBackground=c1)

Label(root,text = 'CHECK URL',bg="black", fg ="cyan", font ='aerial 20 bold').place(x=180, y=35)
link = StringVar()
link_enter = Entry(root, width = 70,textvariable = link).place(x = 32, y = 100)

def ms():
    messagebox.showinfo("About","Simple URL Check")

def main():
    request = "https://unshorten.me/raw/" + link.get()
    response = requests.get(request).text
    listbox.insert(END, response)  #Changed!
    print(response)


frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(width="370", height="215",x="60", y="133")
listbox = Listbox(frame, width="59",height="6")
listbox.pack() #Changed!
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)


Button(root,text = 'Check Url', font = 'aerial 15 bold' ,bg = 'cyan', padx = 2, fg="black", command=main).place(x=203 ,y = 375)
Button(root,text = 'About', font = 'aerial 15 bold' ,bg = 'cyan', padx = 2, fg="black", command=ms).place(x=25 ,y = 375)

root.mainloop()
```